# ASP.NET Core web application not working live but does work locally

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm deploying my application to Azure, but the problem is that some methods, specifically POST methods give a 404 on the live site while they do work locally. I have been trying to debug it using BurpSuite, but it seems as if the requests are similar.

[image: Localhost]

[image: Live site:]

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SavePlan(string PlanDate)
{
    DateTime dateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(PlanDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

    // Get planCart
    PlanCart planCart = GetPlanCart();

    // Validate MealPlan
    if (!ValidateMealPlan(planCart))
    {
        TempData["Error"] = "Error: MealPlan contains has too many diet restrictions per day.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // Create and set MealPlan options
    MealPlan mealPlan = new MealPlan();
    mealPlan.dateFrom = dateFrom;
    mealPlan.dateTo = dateFrom.AddDays(7);
    mealPlan.Meals = planCart.returnList().ToArray();

    mealplanRepository.SaveMealPlan(mealPlan);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Identity server
        services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration["Data:EasyMealIdentityServer:ConnectionString"]));

        // Add OrderCustomersServer
        services.AddDbContext<AppMealOrdersCustomersDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration["Data:EasyMealOrdersCustomersServer:ConnectionString"]));

        // EasyMealMealServer
        services.AddDbContext<AppMealsDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration["Data:EasyMealMealServer:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddTransient<IMealRepository, EFMealRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IOrderRepository, EFOrderRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IMealplanRepository, EFMealplanRepository>();

        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseCookiePolicy();
    }
}
```

Form in View (Index.cshtml):

```
        <form id="PlanForm" asp-action="SavePlan" asp-controller="Plan" method="post">
        <input id="PlanDate" name="PlanDate" value="" type="hidden" />
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save selection</button>
    </form>
```

PlanDate, the parameter required gets set via javascript. You can see in the request in BurpSuite that it does get send. I thought maybe that was the problem.

If anybody has an idea what could be going wrong it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you using iis express or local iis?  what local url are you trying to hit and what is the route config

Comment: Have you got as far as checking that the request is hitting your method? I would definitely add more logging as a first step.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have done so locally, it does indeed hit the breakpoint but I have no idea how I would debug it live.

Comment: @terrencep I am using IIS express, I will update my question.

Comment: @MihaelKeehl There are lots of logging frameworks and places to log your data to. Did you try [starting with the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0)?

Comment: Okay, before you go any further, I'd focus on making sure that you can log from your application, then retrieve those logs. It's often not as easy as I'd expect it to be, but it's really important as a first step.

Comment: @mason / JonSkeet Thank you, I honestly did not know I could do that. A bit dumb of me. I am going to try to figure that out first!

Comment: Excellent - logging is incredibly important to running any sort of production application. There's lots of ways to do it. My company has settled on [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) as a logging framework and [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq) as a place to send those logs. And it's worked out very well for us.

Comment: he's getting a 404, any line of logging or any breakpoints will not be hit. He should add it, but it will not help him here.

Comment: @terrencep  Yes, you can get a 404 from an action that you hit, that has a breakpoint set on it. Have you ever put `return NotFound();` in a controller's action method? That will result in a 404 error. It just depends on the reason for the 404.

Comment: @mason he's not throwing a 404 if the cart is empty, he has a specific error message.

Comment: @terrencep Ah, true enough. I was speaking more generally, but you're talking about in this specific instance. Got ya.

Comment: @terrencep I have absolutely no idea what it is. I've been trying to log the error but it just doesn't get to it, it literally doesn't find the method in the controller. All I get is a 404 without any additional information. I have altered my view code, maybe the problem lies within there. I am updating my question right now to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit 2: you need to format the date client side and use clientinfo server side to avoid mm/dd/yyyy vs dd/mm/yyyy mismatch!

edit 1: 
Are you passing forward slashes in the date? that will break it.
Pass in the date with dashes instead or escape it in javascript.**

right click the project, click properties, click the web tab, scroll down to see the correct iis url with port.

for .net core use launchSettings.json and find the application url.

When you try to post to it, make sure you are doing `localhost:<port>\<controller>\<action>`

so controller is probably home, action is saveplan, and you need \plandate after that

Comment: I think I forgot a bit of essential information, it's a Dot Net Core Web application, not a DotNet Web app. My apologies. I don't see that property you're talking about. Could it just be my routes? Although I don't understand how that would explain why it would work locally but not on the live site.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will first try to figure out how I can log the information then I will come back to this.

Comment: @MihaelKeehl updated my answer, can't believe we missed this.

Comment: yup, added it! format it client side AND use cultureinfo server side.